# Add class to parent div when textarea clicked or focused?

Tags: jquery, textarea, parent, addclass, toggleclass

How to add a class to the textarea's parent div when clicked or focused?

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
$('textarea').toggleClass(function() {
  if ($(this).parent().is('.expandingArea')) {
    return $(this).parent().addClass('open');
  } else {
    return $(this).parent().removeClass('open');
  }
});
});
```

Comment: Do you need to remove the class as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use focus and blur to get this functionality.

```
$('textarea').focus( function() {
  $(this).parent().addClass('open');
});

$('textarea').blur( function() {
 $(this).parent().removeClass('open');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mprabhat/CLVer/1/)

[Another One](http://jsfiddle.net/mprabhat/hgcmv/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.expandingArea > textarea').on({
  'focus' : function() {
     $(this).parent().addClass('open');
   },
   'blur' : function() {
     $(this).parent().removeClass('open');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('textarea').on({
    'click': function() {
        $(this).parents('div.expandingarea').addClass('open')
    },
    'focus': function() {
        $(this).parents('div.expandingarea').addClass('open')
    },
    'blur': function() {
        $(this).parents('div.expandingarea').removeClass('open')
    }
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rB5tn/)**.